# Obtener el track usado para filtrar por API twitter

Tags: nodejs, twitter-api

Estoy usando el API de twitter statuses/filter y track con varios valores de búsqueda para realizar la búsqueda, y quiero saber cual de los parámetros de los que puse para la búsqueda es el que utilizó, se puede realizar esto.
el código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
var filtro= "palabra1, palabra2, palabra3";
client.stream('statuses/filter', 'track': filtro},  function(stream) {
        stream.on('error', function(error) {
            console.log(error);  
        });
    stream.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log(data);});
});
```

Comment: ¿Qué es exactamente lo que devuelve la API?

Comment: El API te devuelve la información relacionada al tweet en secciones, fecha, usuario, ubicación, retweets, urls, pero no encuentro la sección en la que te muestra el match entre las palabras que pusiste de filtro y lo que te devuelve

Comment: Entonces quizás la solución más sencilla sea crear un stream para cada "palabra" y así inequivocamente sabrás cual ha hecho match. Supongo que el problema entonces sería crear una lista con todos los tweets de cada filtro, teniendo en cuenta que no se repitan.